# 10000000000%10 returning 8 in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, modulo

**Q ) To reverse two linked lists, add them and return a reversed linked list of the sum**`
https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/

```java
class Solution 
{
    public long reverse(long num)
    {
        long ans = 0;
        while(num > 0)
        {
            ans = ans*10 + (num%10);
            num /= 10;
        }
        return ans;
    }
    
    public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) 
    {
        
        long num1 = 0;
        long num2 = 0;
        while(l1 != null)
        {
            num1 = num1*10 + l1.val;
            l1 = l1.next;
        }
        while(l2 != null)
        {
            num2 = num2*10 + l2.val;
            l2 = l2.next;
        }
        num1 = reverse(num1);
        num2 = reverse(num2);     
        System.out.println("num1 = " + num1);
        System.out.println("num2 = " + num2);
        long sum = num1+num2;
        System.out.println("sum = " + sum);
        int l = (int)sum%10;
        sum /= 10;
        System.out.println("l = " + l);
        System.out.println("sum = " + sum);
        ListNode head = new ListNode(l);
        ListNode l3 = head;
        while(sum > 0)
        {
            l = (int)sum%10;
            System.out.println("l = " + l);
            System.out.println("sum = " + sum);
            sum/=10;
            ListNode temp = new ListNode(l);
            l3.next = temp;
            l3 = l3.next;
        }
        return head;
    }
}
```

**For the input:**

[9]
[1,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9]

**Output:**

num1 = 9
num2 = 9999999991

sum = 10000000000
l = 8 **(why is 10000000000%10=8 here?)**

sum = 1000000000
l = 0

sum = 1000000000
l = 0

sum = 100000000
l = 0

sum = 10000000
l = 0

sum = 1000000
l = 0

sum = 100000
l = 0

sum = 10000
l = 0

sum = 1000
l = 0

sum = 100
l = 0

sum = 10
l = 1

sum = 1

Please help

Comment: 10000000000 is greater than 2^31 -1 (max value for an int). Just change datatype of `l` from `int` to `long`

Comment: `(int) 10000000000` causes an overflow, leaving you with `1410065408` where its clear that you get `8` as a result when using `% 10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int l = (int)sum%10;
```

The problem is here. You are first casting a ***long*** variable to ***int*** and then calculate the remainder. You might want to check out [Storage sizes for primitive datatypes](https://www.baeldung.com/java-primitives#:%7E:text=Also%20known%20as%20an%20integer,(231%2D1).). There it says the following:

> Also known as an integer, int type holds a wide range of non-fractional number values.
>
> Specifically, Java stores it using 32 bits of memory. In other words,
> it can represent values from -2,147,483,648 (-231) to 2,147,483,647
> (231-1).

In other words, because you are converting a number larger than supported to ***int*** you are getting a loss of data. To fix there problem either cast after finding the remainder:

```
int l = (int)(sum % 10)
```

Or, better yet, just make your variable ***long***.

```
long l = sum % 10
```

Comment: I don't see the wisdom of a `long` variable to hold a value from (-9 to) 0 to 9.